# How to change Kendo UI date format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date string in the following format in JavaScript:

```
"2014-04-10T08:35:18.648Z"
```

I want to change it to this:

```
"2014-04-10 08:35:18.648"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Check [Kendo's documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting). Libraries like that usually have a site full of information on how to use it.

Comment: It will not reomve T and Z character from post date .. When i select date from datepicker it will select proper date as per template set but after post it give me "2014-04-10T08:35:18.648Z".

Comment: kendoui not overcome this problem so i want to some replace function ..on any kind of another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP**

In PHP you can either do something as simple as:

```
$date = '2014-04-10T08:35:18.648Z';
$date = str_replace(array('T', 'Z'), array(' ', ''), $date);

// var_dump($date);
// string(23) "2014-04-10 08:35:18.648"
```

Or this if you prefer a more complicated approach:

```
$date = '2014-04-10T08:35:18.648Z';
preg_match('/^(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d{2})T(?P<hours>\d{2}):(?P<minutes>\d{2}):(?P<seconds>\d{2})\.(?P<ms>\d+)Z$/i', $date, $m);
$date = sprintf('%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%d', $m['year'], $m['month'], $m['day'], $m['hours'], $m['minutes'], $m['seconds'], $m['ms']);

// var_dump($date);
// string(23) "2014-04-10 08:35:18.648"
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

In javascript it's even easier:

```
var dt = '2014-04-10T08:35:18.648Z';
dt = dt.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z', '');

// console.info(dt);
// "2014-04-10 08:35:18.648"
```

Comment: ReferenceError: str_replace is not defined
ReferenceError: preg_match is not defined,,both function not working it give error.

Comment: For Javascript not php

Comment: ReferenceError: array is not defined

Comment: Added the javascript example. In the future please don't add tags (in this case PHP) if they have nothing to do with the question.